# Azure AD B2C- Graphi api Charging

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I looked at the below regarding AzureAD B2C is charged based on

- Number of stored users
- Number of authentications
- Number of multifactor authentications

Is there any specific charge for using the Graph api ? 
Is there any limit on the concurrent graph api calls made

Answer (score 1):

You aren't charged for use of the Azure AD Graph API.

Azure AD Graph is designed to handle a high number of requests. However, in the event of an overwhelming number of requests, [a throttling threshold might be exceeded](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-throttling). Azure AD Graph limits any further requests from the same client while the server throttle is in effect.